# Easy way to store and access commonly used commands?

Tags: shell

I have a bunch of commands that I commonly use. For example:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /home
```

Unfortunately, my brain has very little room left for these sorts of things. I currently keep a text file on my desktop for jotting down these commands -- but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this right from the command line...

Ideally, I could create a alias command that would open a list of my favorite commands...for example:

```
mfc
```

would open *my list of favorite commands* and then I could quickly copy and exit that to do the command. Anybody got a workflow they'd like to suggest on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ctrl+r, start typing a command and then a suggestion will appear of a command in you previously used (and that's in the history).

Answer (score 2):

I can only tell you what I do, since there are a billion ways to approach this.  We use Puppet for systems management at my company so I populate my `.bashrc` with lots of functions and aliases.  For example (your example reminded me of mine):

```
alias sp='du -mx . --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | head'
```

If I ever want to remind myself what I've done, I can look at `.bashrc`, type `alias` and/or `declare -f` (to see functions loaded into my shell).